# XPath how to select an element where the following sibling has an specific child?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I'm trying hard to find an answer but I somehow can't figure out how to find an element who the next sibling has immediate child...

Example:

```html
<p>text</p>
<p>
    <br/>
    <span>text2</span>
</p>
```

In this case how can I:

1. Find all the `<p>` with `text` where it has an adjacent-sibling `<p>` with a first-child `<br>`, I guess this translates into `p + p > br:first-child`?
2. Find all the `<p>` with `text` where it has an adjacent-sibling `<p>` with an any level child `<br>`, I guess this translates into `p + p br`?

What I have tried:

1. `//p[contains(., 'text') and following-sibling::p[br]]`

1.1. `//p[contains(., 'text') and following-sibling::p/*[br]]`

1.2 `//p[contains(., 'text')]/following-sibling::p[br]`

Nothing works, any hope?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first try was close, but it was checking if `<p>` has *any* following-siblings named `<p>` which have a child named `<br>`. But I guess that you really wanted to check if *the first* following-sibling named `<p>` has a child named `<br>` instead.

So use

```
//p[contains(., 'text') and following-sibling::p[1][br]]
```

To get the element only if `<br>` is the *first child*, you can use this extended expression

```
//p[contains(., 'text') and following-sibling::p[1][*[self::br and position()=1]]]
```

To satisfy your second requirement that `<br>` can be at *any* descendant level and not only a direct child, you can use

```
//p[contains(., 'text') and following-sibling::p[1][descendant-or-self::br]]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer :)